accuracy for multi-class image classification not improving past 50%
I am working on a project to predict the brand of jeans based on the pact on the back of the jeans.
To do this I gathered my own data online of 3 different jean brands (arizona, levi, lucky brand) and got about 100 images of each brand. I then did some data augmentation although very basic
def generate_more_images():
    for dir in os.listdir('jean_img'):
        if dir != '.DS_Store':
            n = 0
            for image in os.listdir(f'jean_img/{dir}'):
                
                if image != '.DS_Store':
                    img = Image.open(f'jean_img/{dir}/{image}')
                    img = img.resize((500,500))
                    for i in range(10):
                        img = img.rotate(np.random.uniform(-35,35))
                        brightness_factor = np.random.uniform(0.6, 1.4)
                        enhancer = ImageEnhance.Brightness(img)       
                        img = enhancer.enhance(brightness_factor)
                        if n < 200:
                            img.save(f'jean_img_expand_test/{dir}_expand/{n}_{dir}_{image}')
                        elif n < 300:
                            img.save(f'jean_img_expand_valid/{dir}_expand/{n}_{dir}_{image}')
                        else:
                            img.save(f'jean_img_expand_train/{dir}_expand/{n}_{dir}_{image}')
                        n += 1

Then with these images I trained and tested multiple models which I though would have performed well due to the non-complex nature of these images, but I was surprised to see that at best my models have been performing in the low 60's to high 50's
optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.2, patience=5, min_lr=0.00001)

callback = callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', patience=20, restore_best_weights=True)

model = Sequential([
    layers.Input(shape=(500, 500, 3)), 

    layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same'),
    layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    layers.Dropout(0.25),


    layers.Flatten(),

    layers.Dense(64),
    layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3),
    layers.Dropout(0.5),

    layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')
])
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(
    train_images,
    train_labels,
    epochs=100,
    validation_data=(val_images, val_labels),
    callbacks=[callback, reduce_lr]
)

Here are some of the training images:



I am fairly new to computer vision but I dont think that this classification problem is that difficult. I have done problems with many more classes and the algorithm was able to work very well . I would be extremely grateful if someone was able to point out a flaw in my work.

What do your training loss/accuracy vs. validation loss/accuracy look like ?  This will tell you if you are overfitting or underfitting.
